# listView crashes the application Android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make a button which opens a new activity (tmp) that has a listView of images and titles, but it crashes when I add the listView.

my activity_tmp.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.atheel.atheel.tmp">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my tmp.java:

```
public class tmp extends Activity {
    ListView l;
    String[] data={"one","two","three"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmp);
        l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     R.layout.single_row, R.id.listView1,data);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

my single_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/apple"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `activity_tmp.xml` instead of `activity_order_sent` for Activity Layout

Comment: Go with `Custom ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `R.id.listView1` in the adapter initialization 
it shoudld be `R.id.textView3`

Also the activity layout in setContentView()

Comment: @AtheelMassalha accept it as answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your own Adapter class. Something that inherits from BaseAdapter or CursorAdapter.
Read here:
http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview